# Check if record exists with specific attribute.

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework

I have a form that check it if a record already exists before it allows an insert. The problem i am having is that my deletes don't delete they just hide. So know when I replace a deleted item it sees it already exists. How can i change my code to incorporate the Deleted Bool in the query it does to see if the record already exists.

My record has a attribute of Deleted and it is a bool. If the bool is true (record is deleted) i want it to insert. Otherwise return -1.

```
  // Get Db context
            ItemContext _db = new ItemContext();

            bool ItemExists = _db.Item.Any(i => i.ItemName.Equals(ItemName));

            if(ItemExists)
            {
                return -1;
             }
            else{

            // Add product to DB.
            _db.Item.Add(myItem);
            _db.SaveChanges();
            return myItem.ItemID;
            }
            //Success
```

Comment: Just a note that this may become a bottleneck depending on how may rows you are dealing with. You may want to investigate setting a Unique Index or Constraint on the columns and wrapping your code in a try/catch.

Comment: I am still learning so i dont really know what you mean. Do you know of any good articles that could explain that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your definition of `ItemExists` to include the notion of deleted:

```
bool ItemExists = _db.Item.Any(i => i.ItemName.Equals(ItemName) && !i.Deleted);
```